# A bug in Derivative?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, scoping, debugging

### Update

This is a bug in v11.3 or earlier and is fixed in v12.

### Original Post

Check this out:

```
f[y_] := RootSum[Function[x, x^2 - 1], Function[x, y - x]]
{f'[y], D[f[y], y]}
(*==>{2, 2}*)

g[y_] := RootSum[1 - #1^2 &, y - #1 &]
{g'[y], D[f[y], y]}
(*==>{0, 2}*)
```

The documentation says

> Whenever Derivative[n][f] is generated, the Wolfram Language rewrites it as D[f[#],{#,n}]&.

A simple trace can show the flaw of this rewriting. 
Compare the last line but one:

```
Trace[g'[y]]

{{g^\[Prime],{g[#1],RootSum[#1^2-1&,#1-#1&],
  {(#1^2-1&)[Integrate`$$a[1]],
  Integrate`$$a[1]^2-1,-1+Integrate`$$a[1]^2},
  {(#1-#1&)[Integrate`$$a[1]],
Integrate`$$a[1]-Integrate`$$a[1],-Integrate`$$a[1]+Integrate`$$a[1],0},0},0&},(0&)[y],0}
```

with :

```
Trace[f'[y]]

{{f^\[Prime],{f[#1],RootSum[Function[x,x^2-1],Function[x$,#1-x$]],
  {Function[x,x^2-1][Integrate`$$a[1]],Integrate`$$a[1]^2-1,
  -1+Integrate`$$a[1]^2},
  {Function[x$,#1-x$][Integrate`$$a[1]],
  #1-Integrate`$$a[1]},2 #1},2&},(2&)[y],2}
```

The `#1-#1&` clearly shows the conflict.

Due to some reasons, I prefer to use `Derivative` to `D`, however in some cases, `Integration` returns functions like `RootSum` where `#1` is ubiquitous.

Is this a bug in `Derivative`? 
If it is, how can I bypass this issue while still using `Derivative`?

Comment: In order to bypass it, define g with Set `=` instead SetDelayed `:=` . `g[y_] = RootSum[1 - #1^2 &, y - #1 &];
{g'[y], D[g[y], y]}  `  yields `{2,2}`

Comment: @Akku14 This only counts on the fact that `RootSum` can be simplified at the beginning, for the more complicated cases, it is not correct either, such as `RootSum[1 - #1 + #1^2 - #1^3 &, Log[y - #1] &]` . Here I only post the toy model to show the issue.